# Should I downvote a question if the code in it is highly syntactically inaccurate?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, question-quality

The question: [Can we declare instance variable in singleton service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487020/can-we-declare-instance-variable-in-singleton-service)

Should I downvote a question if the code in it is highly syntactically inaccurate (1), but the question isn't about any syntactic constructions (2)?

Comment: There are reasons to downvote this besides the code in it, for sure.... but as a general answer: yes. You can downvote for whatever reason you want.

Comment: @Patrice of course, I can even downvote a question prior to reading it. Would it be nice and justified?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko once in a while I TL;DR;DV - Too Long, Didn't Read, Down Voted.

Comment: @Andrew no it wouldn't (in my opinion at least). I don't see what other kind of answer you expected though. In a place where voting is a personal choice in regards to "is this useful?" then... yeah there will be people downvoting for a multitude of reasons..... all of them, theoretically, "correct"

Comment: As always though, you should explain that to the poster. "Downvote for numerous syntactic issues, e.g. (point out an overt one).

Comment: @TimConsolazio:  That's poor advice.  You put a target on your back rather than actually explaining what's going on.  The close reasons do a better job of explaining what's wrong with the post and that's what should be relied on here.

Comment: @Tim try "there seems to be numerous synctactic issues in your post, maybe you want to fix that? (and then point one). The main difference is you don't go "I downvoted" which very rarely goes well :/

Comment: "Put a target on your back." This is how SO members think? We need to be anonymous because we're afraid of each other?

And for what it's worth, my comment clearly says to explain it and provide an example.

Comment: @TimConsolazio I would flip it around. Focus on what can be improved such that upvotes become relevant - because that's the true solution, not receiving more downvotes is not going to salvage anything. Content needs upvotes to be salvaged. That is so much more of a positive thing to focus on, and you don't need to do anything as volatile as tying your username to a downvote.

Comment: @TimConsolazio that's the reason why a comment starting with "-1" or "+1" on SO main site is forbidden, because users are discouraged to relate the comment with their votes. The OP doesn't need to know why you vote. They only need to know how to improve the post.

Comment: @TimConsolazio You've cast a grand total of three downvotes, ever.  Rather than making statements about what's considered appropriate behavior by the community (that are the exact opposite of what the rules state is appropriate), and then saying that the entire community is wrong when corrected, you might consider actually engaging in the behavior that you're advising others about (and criticizing the community consensus of) so that you can speak with some practical experience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with any post, you should downvote it if you feel it's not a useful post.  If you think that the syntactic problems it has are significant enough to make the post not useful, you're free to reflect that opinion with your vote.  If you feel that the syntactic problems that the post has don't impact its usefulness (or don't outweigh other thinks making it useful), you're free to reflect *that* opinion in your votes.

As for my personal opinion, I'd say that there are a lot more things going on in that question affecting its usefulness more than the syntactic errors.  There are a lot of problems with it, and most of them are quite a bit more significant than the syntactic errors.  If it was an otherwise good question (which it is not) I don't think those errors would prevent it from being useful.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you don't need to justify a downvote (and trying to do so has cost me downvotes from petty people.)

But, if you do want to justify it to yourself, hover over the down vote arrow a moment before clicking.

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

To me at least, not fixing basic syntax errors displays a complete lack of "research effort." It indicates they can't even bother to try running the code they've posted. I spend most of my time in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and I can assure you I am compelled to exercise this prerogative on a regular basis there.

Answer (score -18):

I haven't looked at the question. You can usually solve syntactic problems by editing the question. So if you think the syntactic problems make the question not useful you have two options.

- By default you downvote it like any other question you consider not useful.
- If you have lots of time on your hands, you can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: You should not be fixing problems with the code in a question.  That runs the risk of potentially fixing the problem that the question is asking about.  You can point it out to the OP in a comment, so that, if it's truly irrelevant to their question, they can remove it.

Comment: *You can usually solve syntactic problems by editing the question.* That may completely change the question, though - maybe the syntactical errors are the source of the OP's problem.